# How to make marker draggable in angular-google-map?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make map marker draggable in Map, so it just make it `draggable="true"`
but it is not working.

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'  control='map.control' id="map-canvas">
     <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" draggable="true" coords="'coords'">
     </ui-gmap-markers>
   </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the controller?

```
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function (info){

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
            draggable: true,
            title: info.city
        });
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });

        $scope.markers.push(marker);

    }
```